# Duplicate Json String Print

Tags: python, json, string

I have this Json:

```
 [{u'PrevDay': 0.00020307, u'Volume': 37185.350516, u'Last': 0.00022451, u'OpenSellOrders': 930, u'TimeStamp': u'2017-07-02T22:58:04.493', u'Bid': 0.00022306, u'Created': u'2015-07-31T00:50:47.11', u'OpenBuyOrders': 196, u'High': 0.00024999, u'MarketName': u'BTC-AEON', u'Low': 0.000198, u'Ask': 0.00023, u'BaseVolume': 8.15021286}, {u'PrevDay': 0.0009134, u'Volume': 92603.74600271, u'Last': 0.00096555, u'OpenSellOrders': 1998, u'TimeStamp': u'2017-07-02T22:58:04.867', u'Bid': 0.0009662, u'Created': u'2017-05-17T19:54:30.143', u'OpenBuyOrders': 422, u'High': 0.001, u'MarketName': u'BTC-ANT', u'Low': 0.00088022, u'Ask': 0.00098754, u'BaseVolume': 84.66436976}, {u'PrevDay': 0.00208098, u'Volume': 9427.31361715, u'Last': 0.00215844, u'OpenSellOrders': 917, u'TimeStamp': u'2017-07-02T22:58:04.07', u'Bid': 0.00215972, u'Created': u'2017-05-02T06:26:32.897', u'OpenBuyOrders': 230, u'High': 0.00224997, u'MarketName': u'BTC-APX', u'Low': 0.00205, u'Ask': 0.00223999, u'BaseVolume': 19.99655187},
```

I want to print `MarketName` with the `TimeStamp` in one line for each of the duplicated strings.

I'm using Python and i tried so far:

```
market = data['MarketName']
time = data['TimeStamp']
print time, market
```

Now i want to print the other strings too but i don't know how.

Comment: What have you tried? Could you add your current code? And how does your problem relate to Python?

Comment: I suggest you show us what you tried so we can show you what you did wrong.

Comment: What's the problem? `print([d['MarketName'] for d in json_list])`

Comment: i want to print all the MarketNames seperated in one line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a loop... In this case, a [`for`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) loop. Loops are meant to iterate over sequences of data. You are on the right track, you just need to make a couple of additions:

```
full_data = [{u'PrevDay': 0.00020307, u'Volume': 37185.350516, u'Last': 0.00022451, u'OpenSellOrders': 930, u'TimeStamp': u'2017-07-02T22:58:04.493', u'Bid': 0.00022306, u'Created': u'2015-07-31T00:50:47.11', u'OpenBuyOrders': 196, u'High': 0.00024999, u'MarketName': u'BTC-AEON', u'Low': 0.000198, u'Ask': 0.00023, u'BaseVolume': 8.15021286}, {u'PrevDay': 0.0009134, u'Volume': 92603.74600271, u'Last': 0.00096555, u'OpenSellOrders': 1998, u'TimeStamp': u'2017-07-02T22:58:04.867', u'Bid': 0.0009662, u'Created': u'2017-05-17T19:54:30.143', u'OpenBuyOrders': 422, u'High': 0.001, u'MarketName': u'BTC-ANT', u'Low': 0.00088022, u'Ask': 0.00098754, u'BaseVolume': 84.66436976}, {u'PrevDay': 0.00208098, u'Volume': 9427.31361715, u'Last': 0.00215844, u'OpenSellOrders': 917, u'TimeStamp': u'2017-07-02T22:58:04.07', u'Bid': 0.00215972, u'Created': u'2017-05-02T06:26:32.897', u'OpenBuyOrders': 230, u'High': 0.00224997, u'MarketName': u'BTC-APX', u'Low': 0.00205, u'Ask': 0.00223999, u'BaseVolume': 19.99655187}]
for data in full_data:
    market = data['MarketName']
    time = data['TimeStamp']
    print time, market
```

This gives:

```
2017-07-02T22:58:04.493 BTC-AEON
2017-07-02T22:58:04.867 BTC-ANT
2017-07-02T22:58:04.07 BTC-APX
```

Comment: for what does the d stands?

Comment: @PeterHansen The `d` is a loop variable. At iteration `i` it receives the `ith` element from data. You can rename it to anything.

Comment: @PeterHansen I don't think you quite follow. Please check my edit. Make sure you use the right variable names.